# Trigger formula on specific date

Tags: formula, process-builder, date

I am trying to set a formula based criteria on process builder:

```
(TODAY() = DATEVALUE(2016,11,29))
```

Trying to say that on a specific date, it should fire the subsequent actions. Am I entering the date correctly? Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good way.

DATEVALUE expects to be like that: 'YYYY-MM-DD', so your date should be like this:

TODAY() = DATEVALUE('2016-11-29')

Comment: Would it be TODAY() = DATEVALUE('2016-11-29' OR '2016-11-30) if I wanted to add multiple dates?

Comment: OR(TODAY() = DATEVALUE('2016-11-29'), TODAY() = DATEVALUE('2016-11-30'))

Comment: I tried to the OR function, the process will evaluate on the first date but it will not evaluate on the second date. Why is that?

Comment: OR means if one of the values are true, so maybe if the first is true it does not need to check the other ones because the whole formula would return true

Comment: So would it be AND? That wouldn't work because you can't have two dates as TODAY(), or can you? Basically, I need the process to run on specific multiple dates, that is every year it needs to run.

Comment: I think OR is good for that - if the first value is false, it will evaluate the second